# Data accumulates (FIFO?) in broadcast UDP socket

Tags: c, sockets, udp, broadcast, fifo

I have a device that sends me a stream of monitoring data (size of 58) every second, in broadcast. I'm reading this stream with a C program. 
My problem is if i don't read this stream for a few seconds, the next time i read it, i got much more datas that i needed, like if i had a FIFO that keeps filling during the time i'm not reading the stream.

I tried using different methods of reading, like using select, non-blocking socket ... always the same. Maybe there is just a detail that i miss ...
Here is an example code :

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* for printf() and fprintf() */
#include <sys/socket.h> /* for socket(), connect(), sendto(), and recvfrom() */
#include <arpa/inet.h>  /* for sockaddr_in and inet_addr() */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* for atoi() and exit() */
#include <string.h>     /* for memset() */
#include <unistd.h>     /* for close() */

#define MAXRECVSTRING 58  /* Longest string to receive */


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sock;                         /* Socket */
    struct sockaddr_in broadcastAddr; /* Broadcast Address */
    unsigned short broadcastPort;     /* Port */
    char recvString[MAXRECVSTRING+1]; /* Buffer for received string */
    int recvStringLen;                /* Length of received string */

    if (argc != 2)    /* Test for correct number of arguments */
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Usage: %s <Broadcast Port>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    broadcastPort = atoi(argv[1]);   /* First arg: broadcast port */

    /* Create a best-effort datagram socket using UDP */
    if ((sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) < 0)
        perror("socket() failed");

    /* Construct bind structure */
    memset(&broadcastAddr, 0, sizeof(broadcastAddr));   /* Zero out structure */
    broadcastAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;                 /* Internet address family */
    broadcastAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);  /* Any incoming interface */
    broadcastAddr.sin_port = htons(broadcastPort);      /* Broadcast port */

    /* Bind to the broadcast port */
    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &broadcastAddr, sizeof(broadcastAddr)) < 0)
        perror("bind() failed");

    /* Receive datagram from the server */
    int g=0;
    int time_to_sleep=10; 
    while(1)
    {
        if(g==10)
        {
            while(time_to_sleep)
            {
                printf("sleep for %d\n", time_to_sleep);
                time_to_sleep=sleep(time_to_sleep);
            }//after that my next read is 10 data stream of 58 in one !!
        }


        if ((recvStringLen = recvfrom(sock, recvString, MAXRECVSTRING, 0, NULL, 0)) < 0)
        {
             perror("recvfrom() failed");
        }
        //later will check the header but for now just the size is enough
        if (recvStringLen==58){ printf("Read okay bc Size = %d \n", recvStringLen); }


    }

    close(sock);
    exit(0);
}
```

So i will try to explain my problem :
My equipment sends me UDP packets (size 58) every seconds that i keep reading continuously. After x time (g==10) i decide to sleep during 10seconds. During these 10seconds my equipment keeps sending UDP packets, but i don't read them and don't want to. At the 11th seconds, when i wake up i want to read my (g==10)+11th packets and not the 11th + the 10 i did not read during i slept.
Unfortunately, when i read the 11th with a single recvfrom i get all the 10 previous one ...

I tried with and without an ethernet switch in case, but same problem. I must misunderstand something in socket ... can you help me ?

By the way, my code may be pure disaster, i'm a beginner. Do not hesitate to correct me !

Thank you !

Comment: It not clear exactly what it happening.  Are you saying that if 10 packets get sent while you're sleeping that you'll read 10 packets?  That's to be expected, as the OS has a buffer for received packets so a small delay doesn't result in dropped packets.  Are you only interested in the most recent?

Comment: Given the code you posted above, I don't see that you would ever execute `sleep`. You set `g=0`. Then, in the loop, you have the statement: `if(g==10)` which guards your `sleep`. But `g` never gets modified so that block will never be entered.

Comment: In any case, there is no way you will get more than one datagram from a single `recvfrom` with UDP. So it isn't clear what you mean by "10 stream in 1". It *is* quite possible, as @dbush said, that you could receive 10 separate queued datagrams in short order if you had been sleeping while they arrived.

Comment: @dbush That's exaclty what happened ! And yes i don't want to read packet sent during the sleep time, only the most recent ... i have no idea the linux OS has a small buffer, how do i get only the last one ?
Thnak you !

Comment: @GilHamilton During the time i sleep, my equipement keep sending every second data packets of size 58. So i sleep 10seconds it will send 10 packets that i will not read. At the 11th second i read the packets, i want to read only the 11th, but i read the 10packets+11th ... sorry for not beiign clear enough ...
So how do i get rid of this "buffer" ? Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I must misunderstand something in socket ... can you help me ?

There are receive and send socket buffers in the kernel. The kernel receives datagrams for your listening socket and stores them in the kernel socket receive buffer. `recvfrom` call copies the oldest datagram from the kernel socket buffer into your user-space buffer. The fact that you do not call `recvfrom` doesn't mean the kernel stops receiving datagrams (you would need to close the socket for the kernel to stop receiving data).

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually getting 10 or 11 packets from a single `recvfrom`.  You're calling `recvfrom` in a loop, and each iteration of the loop reads a packet.  So you need some way of knowing that the most recent packet you read is the "last" one.

The way to do this is to continuously read until there's nothing to read, then you know the most recent is the last one.  The way your code is current written however, if there are no packets to read then `recvfrom` will block until a packet becomes available.  You can change this by putting the socket in non-blocking mode:

```
int fd_flag;
if ((fdflag = fcntl(sock, F_GETFL)) == -1) {
    perror("Error getting socket descriptor flags");
    exit(1);
}
fdflag |= O_NONBLOCK;
if (fcntl(sock, F_SETFL, fdflag) == -1) {
    perror("Error setting non-blocking option");
    exit(1); 
}
```

Now when you call `recvfrom` if there is no data available it will return -1 and set `errno` to `EAGAIN`.  You can use this to check for the "last" packet:

```
while(1)
{
    while(time_to_sleep)
    {
        printf("sleep for %d\n", time_to_sleep);
        time_to_sleep=sleep(time_to_sleep);
    }//after that my next read is 10 data stream of 58 in one !!

    int read_one = 0;
    while (1) {
        if ((recvStringLen = recvfrom(sock, recvString, MAXRECVSTRING, 0, NULL, 0)) < 0)
        {
            if (errno == EAGAIN) {
                // nothing more to read
                break;
            } else {
                perror("recvfrom() failed");
            }
        } else {
            read_one = 1;
            if (recvStringLen==58){ printf("Read okay bc Size = %d \n", recvStringLen); }
        }
    }

    if (read_one) {
        // process last packet read
    } else {
        // nothing read, so do nothing
    }
}
```